# Good bound on $ \max_{|z| \le A} \left | \frac{\mathbb{E} [ X^2 \exp( -z X) ]}{ \mathbb{E} [ X \exp( -z X) ]} \right| $ where $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, probability-distributions, laplace-transform

Consider a random variable $X \in (0,1]$  and consider the following quantity
\begin{align}
\max_{|z| \le A} \left |  \frac{\mathbb{E} [  X^2 \exp( -z X) ]}{ \mathbb{E} [  X \exp( -z X) ]} \right|   
\end{align}
in the above  $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

The question is the following: Can we find a good upper bound on this quantity?

Here is what I did:
\begin{align}
\max_{|z| \le A} \left |  \frac{\mathbb{E} [  X^2 \exp( -z X) ]}{ \mathbb{E} [  X \exp( -z X) ]} \right|  & \le  \max_{|z| \le A}   \frac{\mathbb{E} [ \left |  X^2 \exp( -z X) \right| ]}{|  \mathbb{E} [  X \exp( -z X) ] | } \\
&\le \exp(A) \max_{|z| \le A}   \frac{\mathbb{E} [  X^2   ]}{ | \mathbb{E} [  X \exp( -z X) ]| }\\
&\le \exp(A)  \frac{\mathbb{E} [   X^2   ]}{ \exp(-A)  \mathbb{E} [  X  ] }   \text{ **Edit:** this step is actually not true see comment below }\\
&\le \exp(2 A)  \frac{\mathbb{E} [  X^2   ]}{   \mathbb{E} [  X  ] }\\
& \le \exp(2 A)
\end{align}

My question is, can we do better?  Can some kind of joint optimization be done?

**Edit:** It might be useful to add some examples.

If $X$ uniform, then we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathbb{E} [  X^2 \exp( -z X) ]}{ \mathbb{E} [  X \exp( -z X) ]} = \frac{z}{z-e^z+1}+\frac{2}{z}
\end{align}

**Edit2:**

Note that $ L(z) = \mathbb{E} [  \exp( -z X) ]$ is the Laplace transform of a random variable $X$. The question can be equivalently rested as
\begin{align}
\max_{|z| \le A}  \left|  \frac{L^{(2)}(z)}{L^{(1)}(z)} \right| 
\end{align}

Comment: It is not true in general that $$|\mathbb{E}[X\exp(-zX)]|\geq\exp(-A)\mathbb{E}[X],$$ meaning that the bound $\exp(2A)$ you proposed can fail. And in fact, it does fail in some cases. For example, if $\mathbb{P}(X=\frac{1}{2})=\mathbb{P}(X=1)=\frac{1}{2}$, then $\mathbb{E}[X\exp(-zX)]=0$ for $z=\log4+2\pi i$, rendering the quotient unbounded.

Comment: @SangchulLee   Thank you for pointing this out. I will edit the question

Answer (score 1):

**Partial result**: It can be shown that the ratio in question can never exceed unity for any complex $z$ in the strip $|\text{Im}(z)|<\pi/2.$

To simplify matters a bit, we assume that the pdf of $X$ exists. One first needs to prove the following:

*Lemma:* Suppose for $x\in S$, $G(x)>0$, $F/G$ is bounded above and the $\int_S G(x)dx$ exists. Then

$$\frac{\int_S F(x)dx}{\int_S G(x)dx}\leq \sup_{x\in S}\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}$$

The proof is simple and I will omit it. Now to prove the statement, first note that the square of the ratio in question can be rewritten as $(z=\alpha+\beta i$, pdf of $X$ is denoted by $f)$:

$$\Bigg|\frac{\mathbb{E}(X^2e^{-zX})}{\mathbb{E}(Xe^{-zX})}\Bigg|^2=\frac{\int _{0}^1dx\int_0^x dy~(xy)^2e^{-\alpha (x+y)}\cos(|\beta|(x-y))f(x)f(y)}{\int _{0}^1dx\int_0^x dy~~xy ~e^{-\alpha (x+y)}\cos(|\beta|(x-y))f(x)f(y)}$$

Apply the lemma with $F$ in the numerator and $G$ in the denominator with $|\beta|<\pi/2$ (to ensure the cosine is positive) and noticing that $\sup_{x\in[0,1]\times[0,1]} xy=1$ we conclude that

$$\Bigg|\frac{\mathbb{E}(X^2e^{-zX})}{\mathbb{E}(Xe^{-zX})}\Bigg|^2\leq 1~~, ~~|\text{Im(z)}|\leq \pi/2$$

We note that this bound is optimal in the strip, since it is saturated by the distribution that has $X=1$ with probability $1$.

I have not been able to extend the proof past this strip since that would require a serious refinement of the technique used above, but I believe the conjecture could hold in an even larger domain, since asymptotically as $\beta\to \infty$ the integral favors the values of the integrand close to $x-y=n\pi/\beta$, and for those, $n=0$ is the largest, if $\alpha$ has a large enough value.

Comment: Thanks. Some very innovative ideas.  Quick question. I think the ratio is a holomorphic function. Don't we have that:  bounded holomorphic functions are constant? Wouldn't this mean that the bound needs to grow with A.

Comment: They have to be entire everywhere on the complex plane for this theorem to hold. Since the function is obviously non-constant for most distributions, it cannot be of bounded magnitude everywhere. This is also the reason why I couldn't bound the ratio in the entire complex plane, but only in a strip.

Comment: It is entire, right?  Btw, I added a few edits to the question. Thanks again.

Comment: The function is entire indeed, but I didn't prove it is bounded on $\mathbb{C}$, just a subset of it, so the Liouville theorem does not apply.

Comment: The function need not be entire, since the denominator can vanish in some cases.

Comment: @SangchulLee But wouldn't the top also vanish? In your example, the numerator vanishes, right?

Comment: They don't necessarily have common zeros. For example, you can check my example in the comment under OP.